# unlisting a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this:

```
list = {{a,{1,2,3}},{b,{1,2,4}},{c,{{1,4,5,5},{6,3,2,1}}}}
```

This is a nested list which each element has a name. I want to export it to CSV so I want to un-nest it to look like:

```
unlist = {{a,{1,2,3}},{b,{1,2,4}},{c1,{1,4,5}},{c2,{6,3,2,1}}}
```

As the list is very dynamic, the solution solution should be dynamic as well. I mean in different files the `list` has different lengths but the nesting structure is the same.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Try `list /. {s_, x : {__List}} :> (## & @@  Table[{Symbol[SymbolName[s] <> ToString[i]], x[[ i]]}, {i,       Length@x}])`

Comment: do you mean that you literally have the symbol `c` and would like to end up with `c1` and `c2`?

Comment: What do you mean by `"I want to import it to CSV"`?

Comment: This question needs to be developed further and explained with more clarity.

Comment: @Kuba already gave the solution.... It's been a long time I am using Mathematica for my research, but I am not sure if I understand everything  has done! Can anyone clear it for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution [proposed by Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56949/unlisting-a-nested-list/56970#comment163312_56949), I just deleted the second part of `list` since it has no use here.

```
list = {{a, {1, 2, 3}}, {c, {{1, 4, 5, 5}, {6, 3, 2, 1}}}};
list /. {s_, x : {__List}} :> 
  (## & @@  Table[{Symbol[SymbolName[s] <> ToString[i]], x[[ i]]}, {i, Length@x}])
```

---

And here is an attempt to explain it:

```
list = {{a, {1, 2, 3}}, {c, {{1, 4, 5, 5}, {6, 3, 2, 1}}}};
Module[{foo = Cases[list, {s_, x : {__List}} :> {s, x}], x, s, table},
 Print@foo;
 s = foo[[1, 1]]; Print@s;
 x = foo[[1, 2]]; Print@x;
 Print@{Symbol[SymbolName[s] <> ToString[1]], x[[1]]};
 table = Table[{Symbol[SymbolName[s] <> ToString[i]], x[[i]]}, {i, Length@x}]; Print@table;
 ]
```

> ```
> {{c, {{1, 4, 5, 5}, {6, 3, 2, 1}}}}
> c
> {{1, 4, 5, 5}, {6, 3, 2, 1}}
> {c1, {1, 4, 5, 5}}
> {{c1, {1, 4, 5, 5}}, {c2, {6, 3, 2, 1}}}
> ```

Then `list /. x :> y` means "*take `x` in `list` and replace it by `y`*". Thus

```
list /. foo :> (## & @@ table)
```

means "*take `foo` in `list` and replace it by `(## & @@ table)`*" where `## & @@` is a trick to elegantly insert the `List`s under the `{ci, {li}}` form.

Key points:

- [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html),
- [`Symbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Symbol.html) and [`SymbolName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SymbolName.html),
- [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html).

Comment: My first upvote because of extraordinary helpfulness

Comment: @eldo Thank you :D I tried my best to explain it, I hope it was clear enough :)

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot explain [Kuba's elegant solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56949/unlisting-a-nested-list/56970#comment163312_56949) here is a step for step approach to your problem:

```
list = {{a, {1, 2, 3}}, {b, {1, 2, 4}}, {c, {{1, 4, 5, 5}, {6, 3, 2, 1}, {7, 4, 5}}}};
```

Find the position of the last symbol (`c`):

```
p = First@Last@Position[list, s_Symbol /; s =!= List]
```

> 3

(Since `List` is a `Symbol` I excluded it in the above statement).

Now get the matrix prepended by the last symbol:

```
q = list[[p, 2]]
```

> {{1, 4, 5, 5}, {6, 3, 2, 1}, {7, 4, 5}}

Prepend `q` with `c1`... `ci`:

```
tab = Table[{ToExpression["c" <> ToString[i]], q[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@q}]
```

> {{c1, {1, 4, 5, 5}}, {c2, {6, 3, 2, 1}}, {c3, {7, 4, 5}}}

Find the positions of entries which already had symbols:

```
h = Most@Range@p
```

> {1, 2}

```
list[[h]]~Join~tab
```

> {{a, {1, 2, 3}}, {b, {1, 2, 4}}, {c1, {1, 4, 5, 5}}, {c2, {6, 3, 2,   1}}, {c3, {7, 4, 5}}}

Put everything together:

```
fun[list_] :=
 With[{p = First@Last@Position[list, s_Symbol /; s =!= List]},
  list[[Most@Range@p]]~Join~
     Table[{ToExpression["c" <> ToString[i]], #[[i]]}, {i, 1, 
       Length@#}] &[list[[p, 2]]]]

fun@list
```

> {{a, {1, 2, 3}}, {b, {1, 2, 4}}, {c1, {1, 4, 5, 5}}, {c2, {6, 3, 2,   1}}, {c3, {7, 4, 5}}}

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of what you want.  These are equivalent; take your pick for readability or flexibility.

```
list /. {x_, a : {__List}} :> Thread @ {Array[x, Length@a], a}

list /. {x_, a : {__List}} :> Array[{x[#], a[[#]]} &, Length @ a]

list /. {x_, a : {__List}} :> MapIndexed[{x[First @ #2], #} &, a]
```

> ```
> {{a, {1, 2, 3}}, {b, {1, 2, 4}}, {{c[1], {1, 4, 5, 5}}, {c[2], {6, 3, 2, 1}}}}
> ```

You can use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html) with a *levelspec* if you need to restrict the replacement to a particular depth.

Comment: It's a pity that your elegant AND readable solution didn't get more upvotes. All the more so, since it would be very easy to convert c[1] to the desired c1 with a final (second) replacement.

Comment: @eldo Thanks. :-)